# UIImage is Not Displaying in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiimageview

I am a newbie in iOS.....I have created a table view to display as a contact view..... here i have displayed name and number using the below coding but i was not able to display images even though i used a correct code..... plz help me

```c
names = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Karthick", @"Gopal", @"Suresh", @"Senthil", @"Guna",nil];

images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"per.png",@"per.png",@"per.png",@"per.png",@"per.png", nil];

num = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"9568421301", @"8756324103", @"856472303", @"8796523565", @"9785858569",nil];
```

This is my three arrays and

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [names count];
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    contactTableViewCell *cell = (contactTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[contactTableViewCell  alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.name.text = [names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.number.text = [num objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.conimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see to possible issues:

`UIImage +imageNamed:` only works for images added to the main bundle. check, if you did that.

[From the docs:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiimage_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:)

> #### Declaration
>
> ```
> + (UIImage *)imageNamed:(NSString *)name
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>       *name*     The name of the file. If this is the first time the image is being loaded, the method looks for an image with the specified name
>   in the application’s main bundle.

The other issue could be that the UIImageView `conimage` is never created.
If this is the case, `cell.conimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];` would be identical to `[nil setImage:aImage];` and in contrast to other languages as Java this is a valid call. Any message sent to the nil object will result in nil — and not an exception.
To be able to see, if this indeed is the case, you will have to explain (preferable with code) how your custom cell class looks like.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set *images* instead of **names** in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method as follows

```
    cell.conimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

replace the line in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`with the above line

Comment: sry boss.... i have committed mistake while adding code snippet...... but in real code i have used images only..... then also i am not getting the image.